# How to I display image from mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Please help. Im trying to display the image of each user using their student ID
BUT it displays unknown characters as image on my page as below

%�S$P��H�~Q��-�}Y>ZTW�)�,G����g�~)�1WN�{�,��!���^j-����9�4���K�����

```
$sql_up="SELECT content FROM sp_uploads WHERE s_id= 'RC49557'";
$result_set=mysql_query($sql_up);

while($row_up = mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
 {
    $pp = $row_up['content'];
 } 

    echo "<td>  
 <img style=\"float:right; margin:5px; width:150px; height:150px; padding:10px; \" 
 src=\"  data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64,<?php echo $pp ?>   \"  /> </td>";
```

Comment: You are already in `PHP` at this point `<?php echo $pp ?>`.

Comment: Like chris85 said, remove that and add something like . $pp .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do. You don't need to open PHP tags inside PHP tags.

```
$sql_up="SELECT content FROM sp_uploads WHERE s_id= 'RC49557'";
$result_set=mysql_query($sql_up);

while($row_up = mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
 {
    $pp = $row_up['content'];
 } 

 echo "<td>  
 <img style='float:right; margin:5px; width:150px; height:150px; padding:10px;' 
 src='data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64, $pp' /> </td>";
```

I'm assuming the img data is correct.

Comment: Thanks guys. It worked. Im so glad. Responses so fast. Thanks

Comment: I removed the variable $pp and used      echo ' <td>
  <img style="float:right; margin:0px; width:150px; height:150px; padding:10px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row_up['content'] ).'"/> </td>';